# How to determine injectivity and surjectivity for a map $\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know how to determine injectivity and surjectivity for maps between regular sets, but in this case I've got some problems. How can I solve this?

> Given the following map $\psi:\overline{x} \in
>  \mathbb{Z}_{16}\mapsto \overline{7}\overline{x}\in\mathbb{Z}_{16}$.
>   Without calculating a single element's image, and just using the properties
>   of $\overline{7}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, decide if $\psi$ is injective,
>   surjective or both. If possible, find the inverse of
>   $\psi$.

Comment: $7\times 7=49=3\cdot 16 +1$ so what about $\psi\circ\psi$?

Comment: Note also that injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent for functions between finite sets of the same cardinality.

Comment: I haven't tried nothing, cause I don't know how to proceed. I was able to do inj. and surj. check calculating every single elements. But in this case I can't do that.
@davide: what do you mean? Why $7\times 7$?

Comment: We have $\bar 7 \cdot\bar 7=\bar 1$. Thanks to that you can say what $\psi\circ\psi$ is.

Comment: Let me check if I really understand. I want to resolve the exercise just using the property of $\overline{7}$, so $x=\overline{7}$ and as a consequence $7*7=49\quad 49=3*16+1=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ and?

Comment: Side question: what does the bar on top of the $7$ mean?

Comment: @J.D., the bar means class mod 16.

Comment: Is my comment correct?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to attack the more general question of what you can say about $\psi_a:x\mapsto ax$. Clearly, $\psi_1 = id$ and $\psi_a \circ \psi_b = \psi_{ab}$. In particular, if $ab \equiv 1$ then $\psi_a$ and $\psi_b$ are inverses of each other.

Now, consider whether there is a $b$ such that $7b\equiv 1 \bmod 16$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $7$ is relatively prime to $16$, it is a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, so $7x=7y$ implies $x=y$. Thus, multiplication by $7$ is injective. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is a finite set, multiplication by $7$ is also bijective. The inverse of the map is also multiplication by $7$ since $7$ is its own inverse mod $16$.