# Homomorphism between cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have some confusion in relation to the following question.

> Let $\langle x \rangle = G$, $\langle y \rangle = H$ be finite cyclic groups of order $n$ and $m$ respectively.
>   Let $f : G \mapsto H$ be the mapping sending $x^i$ to $y^i$.
>   Determine the conditions on $n$ and $m$ so that $f$ is going to be a homomorphism.

In verifying the definition of a homomorphism I seem to be able to conclude that there is no restriction on $n$ and $m$ since the definition of a homomorphic mapping is satisfied:

$$ f(x^i x^j) = f(x^{i+j}) = y^{i+j} = y^i y^j = f(x^i) f(x^j)  \tag{1} $$

But assuming $n < m$ we would get

$$f(x^n) = f(e) = e \not = y^n$$

So clearly we have to have $m \mid n.$

My questions are

1. Are there any other conditions on $n$ and $m$ besides $m \mid n.$
2. What exactly did I do wrong in $(1)$?

Comment: For the (1), What would happen if $i+j \ge m$? It always helps to define the map this way: $x^{i(n)} \mapsto x^{i(m)}$. Note that the map may not even be well-defined if $m \nmid n$.

Comment: I'll write up a more detailed answer in an hour if it's still unanswered. This has its direct connection to the universal property of the quotient maps.

Comment: I see that there are many contradictions if $m \not | n.$ My main concern is that $(1)$ seems like such a innocent algebraic manipulation that I would never suspect that something is wrong with it.I would like to hear an "aha" explanation on why one cannot apply the definition of a homomorphism on $f$ so blindlessly.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108862/how-to-determine-injectivity-and-surjectivity-for-a-map-mathbbz-n-to-mathb

Comment: Well, either you use a homomorphism $\mathbb Z \rightarrow G$ (and talk about lifting that homomorphism) or you must face the fact that the Element $x^i$ does NOT determine the number $i$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The discussion about "well-defined" is perhaps a bit obscure. Here's the problem:

Remember that in general, an element of $G$ may have many different "names." For example, if $n=10$, then the element $x^{11}$ is equal to $x$; in fact, $x$ has infinitely many different "names" as a power of $x$:
$$\cdots = x^{-9} = x^1 = x^{11} = x^{21} = \cdots$$

The problem is that the definition of $f$ as given *depends on the name of the element!* That is, if we are furiously working and somebody hands us a power of $x$, say, $x^{3781}$, we are supposed to, unthinkingly, map it to $y^{3781}$. The problem is that $x^{3781}$ is *the same element* as $x$, which we are supposed to send to $y^1$. That means that *unless* $y^1=y^{3781}$, what we have is not really a function: because the *same* input, $x$ (who, when being teased by bullies is called "$x^{3781}$") may be sent to $y^1$ or to $y^{3781}$, depending on what "name" we just heard for it.

Checking that the value of the function is the same *regardless* of what name we are using for an element, even though the function is defined in terms of the *name*, is called "checking that the function is 'well-defined.'"

An example of a function that is not well-defined would be one in which the input is an integer, and the output is the number of symbols used to express that integer. For example, $f(3)$ would be $1$ (because `3` is only one symbol), but $f(4-1)$ would be $3$ (because we are using `4`, `-`, and `1`). This is not well defined as a function of the integers, because $3$ is the same as $4-1$, but $f$ assigns it two different outputs.

So in order for the expression given to actually define a *function*, we **need** the following to be true:
$$\text{if }x^i=x^j,\text{ then }y^i = f(x^i)\text{ is equal to }y^j=f(x^j).$$
Now, $x^i=x^j$ if and only if $i\equiv j\pmod{n}$; and $y^i=y^j$ if and only if $i\equiv j\pmod{m}$. Therefore, we need:
$$\text{if }i\equiv j\pmod{m},\text{ then }i\equiv j\pmod{n}.$$
In other words: every number that is a multiple of $m$ *must* be a multiple of $n$.

This is equivalent to $n|m$.

In fact, you noticed that in what you wrote, because $x^n=e$, so we need $f(x^n)$ to be the same as $f(x^0)$.

Once we know that $n|m$, then $f$ is well defined. *Once* it is well-defined, we can start verifying that it is indeed a homomorphism (it is).  Technically, it's incorrect to start working to see if it is a homomorphism before you even know whether or not it is a function.

Note that the condition actually works if we allow $G$ or $H$ to be infinite cyclic groups, if we call infinite cyclic groups "groups of order $0$". Then $i\equiv j\pmod{0}$ means $i=j$, every number divides $0$, but the only multiple of $0$ is $0$. So if $G$ is infinite cyclic then the value of $n$ does not matter; if $H$ is infinite cyclic then we must have $G$ infinite cyclic.

Comment: I don't agree with your take on well-defined. The rule $x^i\mapsto y^i$ *is* well-defined in the set $\{x^0, x^1, \ldots, x^{n-1}\}$ because every element in this set has a *single* name. The problem is that this rule may *not* be a homomorphism because there is no guarantee that say $x^{2n-3}$ goes to $f(x)^{2n-3}=y^{2n-3}$.

Comment: @lhf: I agree that if we were specifying $0\leq i\lt n$, then the rule would yield a well-defined function. However, I don't see any such specification in the statement of the problem. It just says "sending $x^i$ to $y^i$", with no restrictions on $i$. Of course, checking that it is a homomorphism is important: I note it later in the post, I don't ignore it.

Comment: Right, I assumed that $0\leq i\lt n$ was a natural implicit assumption.

Comment: @lhf: In that case, there is a *different* problem with the definition, which is that it would only make sense if $n\leq m$ (otherwise, $y^i$ for $i\geq m$ would be an "invalid name"). So we would end up with the conclusion that the map only makes sense and is a homomorphism when $m=n$; or else we need to treat the exponent differently in the domain (restricted to a special representation for the elements) but *not* the codomain, which seems somewhat perverse.

Comment: I don't think $y^i$ is an invalid name. Just raise $y$ to $i$. The exponent is well defined, isn't it?

Comment: @lhf: Again: *if* you are saying that $\langle x\rangle$ consists **only** of $\{x^0,x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$, then you must be seeing $\langle y\rangle$ as $\{y^0,y^1,\ldots,y^{m-1}\}$. Then the interpretation of $x^i$ on the LHS is one "thing" (the special name we gave to the elements of the group $\langle x\rangle$), whereas the interpretatio of $y^i$ on the RHS is a different "thing" (the $i$th power of the generator $y$, regardless of the order of $y$). While it *can* be done so, seems to me to be somewhat perverse, as I noted. Same notation, same equation, different contextual meanings.

Comment: You do have a point there.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I believe you reversed $m$ and $n$ in "if $i\equiv j (\mod m)\ldots$" and on from there. Your conclusion should be that $m\mid n$.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check first if the map is well defined, ie., if $x^i=x^j$ does it follow that $f(x^i)=f(x^j)$?

Comment: +1 Why would anyone downvote this? Ok, it would be better to phrase it: "if $x^i=x^j$ does it follow that $y^i=y^j$?" It is somewhat dangerous to talk about values of $f$ **before** you know that $f$ is well defined.

Comment: it is perfectly acceptable to ask whether or not a definition of f makes f a function.

Comment: @David, you're right, of course. I was just trying to guess, why there was a downvote for a little while.

Answer (score 3):

The rule $x^i\mapsto y^i$ gives a perfectly well-defined function in the set $\{x^0, x^1, \ldots, x^{n-1}\}$. However, for that rule to be a homomorphism we need that $x^{i+j} \mapsto y^{i+j}$ for all $i$ and $j$. To find where $x^{i+j}$ goes we need to reduce $i+j \bmod n$ to a $k$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and we need that $k \equiv i+j \bmod m$. In other words, we need $k \equiv k' \bmod n \implies k \equiv k' \bmod m$ and this can only happen when $m\mid n$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this completely explains why the naive calculations in $(1)$ are not valid. Here is my go at it:

I'll list down several points of concern.

- Firstly your map $x^i \mapsto y^i$ is very naive that it misses some essential details.

> For convenience of notation, I prefer to look at this as $\varphi(\bar i)=\bar i$ if you'll allow me to do so. This is also naive but to some extent captures what is happening.
>
> **So, an equivalence class $\bmod n$ is mapped to the same equivalence class $\bmod m$ under $\varphi$.** This bit of information is missed in $x^i \mapsto y^i$. This explains my comment under your question that you will want to write your maps as $x^{i(n)} \mapsto y^{i(m)}$. This notation makes things more transparent.

That you have dicovered that $m \mid n$, it can be obtained through the universal property of the quotients, which I will write about later.

The quotient map $G \to G/H$ factors over $G \to G/K$ if and only if $K \subseteq H$. That is there is a map from $G/H$ to $G/K$ if and only if $K \subseteq H$.

**Proof**: Please Go through Dummit and Foote's description in their Abstract Algebra in the section $\S3.3$ *Isomorphism Theorems.*

Now consider your cyclic groups as $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ and observe that above condition will tell you, $m\Bbb Z \subseteq n \Bbb Z$ whic happens if and only if...

---

As you had earlier in your comments observed, the map won't even be well defined if $m \nmid n$.

---

I'll leave it to you as a challenge to use this blooper to prove that two groups of same order are isomorphic, which really is not the case.   **Hint**: Cyclic groups exist for any given order.

Comment: Will the down voter explain why?

Comment: Why do you say that $y^{i+j}$ might not be an element of $H$? Of course it is an element of $H$! A group is a set closed under the group operation, so if $y$ is in there, so are all its powers. Also, are you sure that $i(m)$ is a standard notation for the remainder? Color my old-fashioned, but I think that binary mod should stay in programming classes. This last bit is just a pet-peeve of mine :-)

Comment: Firstly, understand that $y^{i+j}$ as it stands is not an element of the group. You need to read that modulo the order of the group. As for the notation, I am pretty sure it is not a very bad notation.

Comment: Well, $y^{i+j}$ **is** an element of the group. For example, if $H$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of complex numbers generated by the imaginary unit $i$, you seem to be saying that $i^5$ is not an element of $H$. Well, you are wrong:
$$i^5=i^{4+1}=i^4\cdot i=1\cdot i=i.$$ Looks like it is in there! The same holds for all cyclic groups. I just picked a concrete one to make you realize your error.

Comment: Well, I am not sure I am at fault. $i^5$ is not an element in the group without reading it modulo the order. Let's wait for someone else to clarify.

Comment: $i^5=i$ true or false? If true, then you must admit that $i^5$ is in the group. Similarly in the group $\mathbf{Z}_5^*$ we have
$2^1=2$, $2^2=4$, $2^3=2^2\cdot2=4\cdot2=8\equiv3$, $2^4=8\cdot2=16\equiv1$, $2^5=2^4\cdot2=1\cdot2=2$ et cetera (all the congruence modulo 5).

Comment: True. But, when doing a symbol pushing, you are prone to making a mistake!

Comment: No. I'm not prone to making a mistake. I check that my mappings are well-defined. If (granted, a big if in some cases) $y^i=y^j$ whenever $x^i=x^j$, then the mapping $x^i\mapsto y^i$ is trivially a homomorphism:
$$f(x^i*x^j)=f(x^{i+j})=y^{i+j}=y^i*y^j=f(x^i)f(x^j)$$
AFTER I have checked that it is well-defined, then the above always makes sense, because in a cyclic group the power of an element is defined in such a way that we always have $y^{i+j}=y^i*y^j$ and so forth.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: I don't agree with your reading. By definition, $i^5$ means $ii^4$, which mean $iii^3$, which means $iiii^2$, which means $iiiii$. If you are in a group (in fact, in a semigroup) and $i$ is in the group, then $i^5$ is in the group, period. The issue is indeed well-definedness *of the map*, not of the expression on the right hand side.

Comment: @Arturo I understand quite the fact that it is misleading. But is the whole answer wrong?

Comment: @Jykri I have got rid of the paragraph but I am not buying your point about the notation, though. I am sorry about pushing hard on something which is quite misleading,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have edited it now. I'd appreciate your comments.

Comment: as a matter of fact, it IS true that $(i+j)$ (mod n) = $i$ (mod n) + $j$ (mod n). the problem is that $(i+j)$ (mod n) may not equal $i+j$ (mod m).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry I spelt your name wrongly. I'll explain the notation and Thank you for removing the downvote.

Comment: and I don't get that part about presumptuousness. Please go ahead and edit it if you feel necessary (or you feel that I might not understand what you want to say.) I once again apologise sincerely. I didn't intend to be rude. And, I usually am not rude, as might be evident from my being here at the site.

Answer (score 0):

THEOREM:

Define $f:\langle x \rangle \to \langle y \rangle$,
where the orders of
$\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$
are n and m respectively,
by $f(x) = y^u$. Then f is a well-defined homomorphism if and only if
$\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)} \mid u$.

PROOF:
Suppose that the mapping
$f:\langle x \rangle \to \langle y \rangle$
is a well-defined homomorphism.

Let
$f(x) = y^u$ for some non negative integer u.

We must also have
$ 1 = f(x^n) = y^{un}$

Then
$ m \mid un$.
Let
$g = \gcd(m, n)$.
Then
$\frac m g \mid u \frac n g$.
It follows that 
$\frac m g \mid u$.

The converse is pretty straightforward.

Suppose we define $f:\langle x \rangle \to \langle y \rangle$
by $f(x) = y^u$ where $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)} \mid u$

The only real problem with this definition is "Is it well defined?"
Since the order of $\langle x \rangle$ is $n$:

\begin{align*}
   x^a = x^b &\Rightarrow a \equiv b \mod n \cr
             &\Rightarrow ua \equiv ub \mod {un} \cr
             &\Rightarrow ua \equiv ub \mod {\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}} \cr
             &\Rightarrow ua \equiv ub \mod {m} \cr
             &\Rightarrow y^{ua} = y^{ub}\cr
             &\Rightarrow f(x^a) = f(x^b)
\end{align*}

Linearity is pretty obvious, so $f$ is a well-defined homomorphism.

So, if you want $f(x^i) = y^i$, then you want $f(x) = y$.
You must therefore have $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)} \mid 1$. Which implies $m \mid n$.

Conversely, if $m \mid n$ and $f(x) = y$, it follows that $f(x^i) = y^i$.